# SBT Plugin: Use inputTask to override settingKey before run taskKey?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a `task` which take `settingA` and settingB` as input to run.

I would like to have a `inputTask` which would override `settingA` and run `task` with the new value of `settingA`.

How would one do that ?

Thank you.

**More details:**

Task would be something like:

```
Def.taskDyn {
   val settingAValue = settingA.value
   val settingBValue = settingB.value

   Def.task {
      settingAValue + settingBValue
   }
}
```

people would use it in their `build.sbt`:

```
settingA := 3
settingB := 1
```

and then `sbt task` would yield `4`

I would like a `inputTask` like:

```
Def.inputTaskDyn {
  val newValue = customParser.parsed

  Def.taskDyn {
     val settingCValue = settingC.value

     Def.task {
        // call task with settingA = newValue ? 
     }
  }
}
```

**Edit:**

If that makes it easier, `settingA` could be a `Task` instead of a `Setting`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
lazy val setting1 = settingKey[String]("")
lazy val setting2 = settingKey[String]("")

lazy val task1 = taskKey[Unit]("")
lazy val inputTask1 = inputKey[Unit]("")

setting1 := "a"
setting2 := "b"

task1 := {
  println(setting1.value + setting2.value)
}

inputTask1 := {
  val newValue = Parsers.spaceDelimited("arg").parsed.head
  val curState = state.value
  val updState = Project.extract(curState).appendWithoutSession(
    Vector(setting1 := newValue),
    curState
  )
  Project.extract(updState).runTask(task1, updState)
}
```

Basically, you can rely on the fact that the SBT build state is fully introspectable, and it is possible to modify it and run a task with a new state.

However, documentation advises against using this in tasks. In general, SBT model is that all settings are effectively immutable - you cannot and should not modify them during task execution. Instead, it is suggested to use [commands](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Commands.html) for this purpose:

```
commands += command1

lazy val command1 = Command.args("command1", "") { (state, args) =>
  val updState = Project.extract(state).appendWithoutSession(
    Vector(setting1 := args.head),
    state
  )
  val (finalState, _) = Project.extract(updState).runTask(task1, updState)
  finalState
}
```

Note that this command leaves `setting1` set to the provided value after it is executed. If you don't want to do it, you should return the original state value, or, better yet, save the original value of `setting1` to a local variable and reinstate it back after the task is run:

```
lazy val command1 = Command.args("command1", "") { (state, args) =>
  val newValue = args.head
  val originalValue = Project.extract(state).get(setting1)

  val updState = Project.extract(state).appendWithoutSession(
    Vector(setting1 := newValue),
    state
  )
  val (nextState, _) = Project.extract(updState).runTask(task1, updState)

  Project.extract(nextState).appendWithoutSession(
    Vector(setting1 := originalValue),
    nextState
  )
}
```

Unfortunately, API is not very intuitive (e.g. you have to call `Project.extract` a lot), but it is the proper way to do what you want. Note that it is possible to construct a command in a variety of ways, including cases when you have your own `Parser`; I've used `Command.args` above for simplicity.

Comment: Thank you for your help ! How would you use a Parser within a command ?

Comment: instead of saving the values and re set them back, cant I just return the original state ?

Comment: Please see the `Command` factory methods - there are some which accept a parser or a function from `State` returning a parser. And yes, I guess you can return the original state, although I don't know how important it is that you don't return state which results from task invocation.